# PHP сохраняет поврежденный файл

Tags: php, android, linux, windows, url

Существует задача: сохранить файл по ссылке с помощью PHP и предоставить к нему доступ в Android приложении.

Ниже приведен код, который занимается сохранением файла.

```
function SaveFile($URL, $Path) {
    return copy($URL, $Path);
}
```

Предположим, необходимо сохранить музыкальный файл в формате MP3. Функция успешно сохраняет файл на сервер (расширение у файла на сервере отсутствует), однако, скачав и установив расширение файлу в OS Windows, он воспроизводится некорректно. Музыки не слышно, лишь какие-то странные звуки.

С изображением абсолютно так же - исходный файл практически не распознать.

К слову, тот же музыкальный файл успешно воспроизводится средствами MediaPlayer OS Android.

Почему так происходит? И как это можно исправить?

Альтернативная функция.

```
private function SaveFile($URL, $Path) {
    $ReadFile = fopen ($URL, "rb");
    if ($ReadFile) {
        $WriteFile = fopen ($Path, "wb");
        if ($WriteFile){
            while(!feof($ReadFile)) {
                fwrite($WriteFile, fread($ReadFile, 4096));
            }
            fclose($WriteFile);
        }
        fclose($ReadFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: А размер файла стал немного больше после сохранения, ну совсем немножко? Если дадите пример такого "битого файла", то скорее всего скажу причину

Comment: Да, размер файла слегка увеличился. Вот, например, изображение. https://mega.nz/#!ZIgCSRyC!1DgxXCI1NYNYYcI9ZuAekE5wOweI9gozstrdbZjRTmU

Comment: @KoVadim, также могу отправить аудио, если необходимо.

Comment: на картинке нарисована обложка для какого то shinedown?

Comment: Верно, обложка альбома.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, PHP нужно расширение файла, чтобы корректно записать файл. Причина этого требования мне неясна, но, по-видимому, указание "?b" не гарантирует принудительное включение бинарного режима. Однако это лишь мое предположение - оно может быть ошибочным.

В общем, переменная `$Path` должна иметь расширение файла.

Comment: при наличии расширения, php автоматом выставит правильные заголовки

Comment: Сервер, с которого берутся файлы, отдает верные заголовки. К примеру,- если аудио файл,- `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`. А после того, как он будет сохранен, файл загружается на компьютер по FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Краткий ответ `s/0x0d0x0a/0x0a/g`.

Полный ответ. В винде есть такое понятие как открытие текстового файла и бинарного (в линуксе оно лишено смысла). Суть заключается в том, что если файл открыть как бинарный, то все в него пишется так, как ожидается, а если как текстовый, то символ перевода строки  `\n` (0x0A) будет кодироваться как 0х0D 0x0A. А для картинок/музыки это почти всегда смертельно. Собственно, эта бага и описана в документации php на функцию [fopen](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php).

Что делать? Либо перевести сервер на линукс, либо у функций fopen (и им родственным) добавить к второму параметру букву b.

Comment: Сервер на Linux, для fopen установлен режим "rb"

Comment: надо искать, может ещё где то быть. Может быть Вы отдаете картинку с хедерами `test/plain` и уже браузер это конвертит

Comment: Передаю ссылку на файл в PHP через POST запрос. После отдаю ссылку в функцию,- добавил альтернативную функцию в вопрос,- она производит чтение и сохранение.

Comment: попробуйте выставить правильные заголовки для ответа. то есть, для картинки в jpeg `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Файл с сервера берется по FTP.